# How can I make redirects from my secure website sent with HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: javascript, html, idxbroker

I'm using an external service ([IDXBroker](https://www.idxbroker.com/)) to embed elements like a search bar into my real estate website via their script tag widgets. Before my website was not SSL secure and did not use HTTPS, so the search bar widget redirect was sent with HTTP, and the redirected IDXBroker page looks normal. However, now that I have secured my website, the redirect somehow now becomes sent with HTTPS, and the styling is screwed up because IDXBroker wants the request to be HTTP.

I can't change anything about the actual IDXBroker widget because I can't change anything under the script tag. Is there a way I can tell my website to stop "upgrading" the http request to https and behave as it was when my website wasn't secure?

Thanks!

Comment: But then your website wouldn't be secure?!

Comment: I would contact IDXBroker or look through their FAQs because I doubt that their widgets don't offer a secure connection

Comment: Related - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your website is now secure with HTTPS, then you will want to enable HTTPS for your IDX Broker pages in your account under Account -> Details when logged in.

Support Article: https://support.idxbroker.com/support/s/article/enable-https-or-ssl-on-your-idx-site

This will make sure you do not run into mixed content issues as stated above. I would recommend forcing http -> https redirects just as your website would to ensure everything is secure.

Comment: Wow! That's perfect, I had no idea that setting existed. Thank you so much.